# TextViewCompat does not works during autosizing of text view (for support library)

Tags: android, textview, autosize

I know, that for using of autosizing `TextView` before `API 26` we should use `TextViewCompat`

I have such view

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_text"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/number_picker_text_height"
    android:background="@color/accent"
    app:customFontName="Fabriga-Light"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="36sp"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="6sp"
    tools:text="223"/>
```

And such code

```
  TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(
        tvValue, TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM);
    TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(
        tvValue, 12, 36, 6,
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP
    );
    int[] preset = new int[]{12, 18, 24, 30, 36};
    TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes(tvValue, preset, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP);
```

But, my view shows dots.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use an amazing library
https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview

Answer (score 0):

I try  `android:singleLine="false"`, and it works